# Why an additive function in number theory is not the same thing as an additive function in algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, functions, definition

I mean why in algebra and analysis [the requirement is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map)

$$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$

while in number theory [it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_function)

$$f(xy) = f(x) + f(y) \;?$$

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you are asking.  Words often have different meanings in different contexts, even in math.  A field in algebra is not the same as a field in vector calculus, for example.

Comment: Because algebra, analysis, and number theory are different branches of mathematics with different histories which developed different jargon for different things, and because the English language only has a finite number of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the functions $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ satisfying $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ are linear...